# Python: Script in python to update a record in mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to update a record in mongoDb. But i am getting an error

```
flag = raw_input('do you want to update?')
    if (flag == 'Y' or flag == 'y'):
            student_name = raw_input("enter studentname to update:")
            student_grade = raw_input("enter grade to update:")
            student_record = {'name':student_name,'grade':student_grade}
            db.collection.update({'name':name},"$set":student_record},upsert=0)
            flag = 0
```

Here i dont know how to update. May be i am following the wrong syntax for update.

Could anyone lend a helping hand?

Here i am using upsert because if record not found for update then it will insert a new record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `{` in your *update* document. `{"$set": student_record}`. Also you need to convert "student_grade" to float. By default `upsert: False` so you don't need to specify. Your *if* statement can by simplify as: `if flag.lower() == 'y':`

```
flag = raw_input('do you want to update?')
if flag.lower() == 'y':
    student_name = raw_input("enter studentname to update:")
    student_grade = float(raw_input("enter grade to update:"))
    db.collection.update_one({'name': student_name}, {"$set": {'grade': student_grade}})
```

Last and not least  the [**`update`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) method is deprecated. You should use the new API. [**`update_one`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one)

Comment: May i know what is "name" you used in :

db.collection.update({'name': name}, {"$set": {'name': student_name, 'grade': student_grades}})

Comment: Well I though  it is a variable somewhere in your code

Comment: yeah, but here i am getting error as "name error" in the particular line. could you help me out?

Comment: @hari are you trying to update document with where `name == student_name`?

Comment: Exactly yes. i am trying to update grade against student name